# watchOS: Fetching EventKit calendars - more than enabled

Tags: ios, swift, watchos, eventkit

I have a watchOS (only) app and fetching calendars and events for these calendars. In my Watch App I have set the calendar app to mirror the calendars from iPhone. When I now uncheck a calendar on iPhone as active my app still get this disabled calendar when fetching all calendars.

Why do I get disabled calendars from EventKit? This is the line I am using to fetch calendars:

```
EKEventStore().calendars(for: .event)
```

Also the problem occurs when I set calendars not to mirror, instead set custom calendars for the watch still all calendars got fetched.

How can I just fetch the calendars that are really active.
The calendars only have these properties, so nothing where I can check if active or not:

```
EKCalendar <0x127fb6f0> {title = Test1; type = CalDAV; allowsModify = NO; color = #1BADF8;}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I had submit an apple TSI. The result is that this functionality is not supported. The answer:

We have reviewed your request and have concluded that there is no supported way to achieve the desired functionality given the currently shipping system configurations.